# Plotly, how to supply manually median, q1,q3, lowerfenc,upperfence in boxplot

Tags: r, plotly

does anyone know ho to supply manualy the tipical value of a box plot in plotly fo R?
on plotly website they said that is possible to provide the requested info simply typing them inside the plotly function:

```
df<-data.frame("xaxis"="a","lowerfence"=1,"q1"=1.3,"median"=2,"q3"=2.5,"upperfence"=4)

df%>%
plot_ly(
x=~xaxis,
median=~median,
q1=~q1,
q2=~q2,
lowerfence=~lowerfence,
upperfence=~upperfence,
type="box"
)
```

but doesn't work.

I have plotly 4.9.0 insatlled, this is the link of plotly reference:https://plot.ly/r/reference/#box

Comment: I think that this is probably referring to the JS library rather than the R wrapper. If you [search the github repo](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/search?q=upperfence&unscoped_q=upperfence) there's no handling of `upperfence`

Comment: This functionality will be available in the R version of the library in a couple of weeks!

Comment: @nicolaskruchten thank you this will be a usefull upgrade!